# Add complete contact object from Facebook to SqLite

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I can't add name and image from Facebook contacts to SqLite, becouse adding is inside in loop and loader start when Event is Complete. Fllowing code adds data to the database, but in the name of the object is the last person out of the loop. Any thoughts? Thanks!

```
        private var person:PersonVO;

    protected function handleFriendsLoad(response:Object, fail:Object):void 
    {
        if (fail) { return }

        var friends:Array = response as Array;
        var l:uint=friends.length;

        for (var i:uint=0;i<l;i++) {
            var friend:Object = friends[i];

            FacebookDesktop.api('/'+friend.id, loadData);
        } 
    }

    private function loadData(object:Object, fail:Object):void
    {
        if (fail) { return; }

        var loader:Loader = new Loader();
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageToByteArray);
        loader.load(new URLRequest(FacebookDesktop.getImageUrl(object.id, 'large')));

        person = new PersonVO()

        person.name = object.first_name;
    }

    private function imageToByteArray(event:Event):void
    {
        var wczytaj:Loader = (event.target as LoaderInfo).loader;
        var image:Bitmap = Bitmap(wczytaj.content);
        var encoderJpeg:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder();
        var byteArray:ByteArray = encoderJpeg.encode(image.bitmapData);

        person.image= byteArray;

        insert(person);
    } 

    private function insert(person:PersonVO):void
    {
        dbStatement.text = "INSERT INTO person (name,image) values(:name,:jpeg)";
        dbStatement.parameters[":name"] = person.name; 
        dbStatement.parameters[":jpeg"] = person.image; 
        dbStatement.execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend `Loader` class functionality:

```
 dynamic class DynamicLoader extends Loader{}
```

Then store whatever you want in instances of `DynamicLoader`:

```
private function loadData(object:Object, fail:Object):void
{
    if (fail) { return; }

    var person:PersonVO = new PersonVO();
    person.name = object.first_name;

    var loader:DynamicLoader = new DynamicLoader();
    loader.person = person;
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageToByteArray);
    loader.load(new URLRequest(FacebookDesktop.getImageUrl(object.id, 'large')));
}

private function imageToByteArray(event:Event):void
{
    var wczytaj:DynamicLoader = (event.target as LoaderInfo).loader as DynamicLoader;
    var image:Bitmap = Bitmap(wczytaj.content);
    var encoderJpeg:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder();
    var byteArray:ByteArray = encoderJpeg.encode(image.bitmapData);

    var person:PersonVO = wczytaj.person;
    person.image= byteArray;

    insert(person);
}
```

I have not used `private var person:PersonVO;`. So if you are not using it in the other methods of your class, you could remove it completely.